# python psutil.cpu_count() returns wrong number of cpus

Tags: python, psutil

I used slurm to allocated 32 cpus. However, when I use cpu_count functions from psutil to get the number of available cpus, it returns only 16 cpus available. Why cpu_count returns less number than actual number of cpus?

Comment: Please add the code snippet you are using. We can better understand the issue that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of psutil

> Note that this number is not equivalent to the number of CPUs the current process can actually use. That can vary in case process CPU affinity has been changed, Linux cgroups are being used or on Windows systems using processor groups or having more than 64 CPUS.

The docs suggest the following for what you want

```
>>> len(psutil.Process().cpu_affinity())
```